# sql column with row-by-row subquery

Tags: sql, mariadb

Given a table like:

| id | Order | dates | status | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 2020-05-10 | Request | some description |
| 2 | 62 | 2020-10-15 | Request | some other description |
| 3 | 55 | 2020-05-11 | Processing | some description |
| 4 | 72 | 2020-06-09 | Pending | another description |

I'd like to have a view with an added column that would show me the completion status.
So, in effect, Incomplete orders are the ones that have ONLY a single record with Request status, but nothing else.
Note that my example table even has a badly completed order. It has no initial "Request" status (order 72), but since every other status is considered as a "completion", the IncompleteOrder column should be FALSE

This structure is used to log interaction calls with clients, so as you can see, each order number might have 0,1 or several records indicating status changes.
I am NOT able to modify this structure because it's an already made system.

The result I'd like to have (using mariaDB) is

| Order | description | IncompleteOrder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | some description | FALSE |
| 62 | some other description | TRUE |
| 72 | another description | FALSE |

order 72 is considered "complete" just because it is not in "request" status

Accomplishing that would be enough, but it would be even better to know what the last status is (since there is a date field):

| Order | date | status | description | IncompleteOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 2020-05-11 | Processing | some description | FALSE |
| 62 | 2020-10-15 | Request | some other description | TRUE |
| 72 | 2020-06-09 | Pending | another description | FALSE |

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . I think window functions are the simplest solution:

```
select t.*, (cnt_order = 1 and cnt_request = 1) as is_complete_order
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by order order by dates desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by order) as cnt_order,
             sum(status = 'Request') over (partition by order) as cnt_request
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply GordonSeems to be working in a small test dataset. I'll be checking with a larger one soon enough while maybe giving some time for other possible answers.. Seems I have to have a look at these windows functions.